# RSpec controller test: How do I check @organization.destroy is being called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I thought it might be like:

```
let(:organization) { mock_model(Organization).as_null_object }

before(:each) do
  Organization.stub(:find).and_return(organization)
end

it "calls the destroy action on @organization" do
  assigns[:organization].should_receive("destroy")
  post :destroy, :id => organization.id
end
```

..but I get a "can't modify frozen object" error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write that spec:

```
describe 'Oragnization#destroy' do
  let(:organization) { mock_model(Organization, :id => 1, :destroy => true) }

  subject { post :destroy, :id => organization.id }

  it { should be_successful }
end
```

Comment: but what's the remaining test if he removes the expectation?

Comment: Yeah - I don't see how this explicitly tests that the destroy action is being called... or is this just the common way to do it?